# setState() vs notifyListeners(), which one is more efficient?

Tags: flutter, dart

I always aim to make my widgets `Stateless` instead `Stateful` for performance benefits. In some cases(updating the `BottomNavigationBar` index e.g.) `notifyListeners()` can provide identical functionality of the `setState()`.

At first, I think `notifyListener()` is lower level, more fundemantal function comparing to `setState()`, so it should be more efficient. Because `setState()` method may triggers too many higher level `framework` methods, so it may spends more CPU power.

But it's hard to be sure without making a proper and detailed performance testing. So what is the answer?

Edit: Also, in some cases, `notifyListeners()` behaves exactly like `setState()`. For example, I have `Text` widget inside a `StatelessWidget` that holds a `Random` value and when I notify the an unrelated value inside the Class, the `Text` widget is also getting update. So, what is the difference?

Comment: it's premature optimizations

Comment: In my opinion this is kind of waste of time. You have to optimise the code that has an high impact on user experience. So if you optimise from 0.02 ms to 0.01 ms and for this optimisation you've spent 4h when you could optimise another piece of code from 4s to 2s in the same amount of time, I would go for the second option. Also I think @Eugene was a bit more polite than I am but I think we are trying to say the same thing.

Comment: @danypata no problem :), I'm here to learn. Tell you what, there are also other benefits of using a class(similar to BLoc) for each route, it makes the code more organized. Widget tree and Widget logic completely seperated and it makes the code way cleaner. That's the main benefit if so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming that you're comparing `ChangeNotifier.notifyListener` with `State.setState` to rebuild the widget tree, then:

`setState` will always win.

The reason, `notifyListener` rebuilds your widget tree because it causes `setState` itself.

For `notifyListener` to work, there's usually a `StatefulWidget` somewhere in your tree that does the following:

```dart
class MyState extends State<T> {
  ChangeNotifier notifier;

  initState() {
    notifier.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }
}
```

In any case, this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting. Thanks Remi!

Comment: I wonder why the Chromium team used this in their berlin demo if  `setState` was simpler! https://github.com/mjohnsullivan/berlin_transport. `setState` seems simpler than the lot.

Comment: I also wonder why the "Your first Flutter app" uses notifyListener() in state management. That's why I landed here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#5

Answer (score -2):

Both setState() and notifyListeners() serve different purposes and are efficient in their respective use cases.

1. setState(): It is used to update the state of a stateful widget and trigger a rebuild of the widget and its subtree.
   When you call setState(), Flutter efficiently rebuilds only the part of the widget tree that depends on the updated state.
   setState() is suitable for managing simple and localized state within a single widget or a small subtree of widgets.
2. notifyListeners():
   It is used to notify listeners (usually widgets) that the state managed by the ChangeNotifier has changed.
   When you call notifyListeners(), only the widgets that are directly listening to the ChangeNotifier are rebuilt, not the entire widget tree.
   notifyListeners() is efficient for managing more complex state that needs to be shared across multiple widgets.
   It is suitable for scenarios where you have a centralized state management system and need to avoid "prop drilling," passing state through a long chain of widgets.

Efficiency Comparison:

In terms of efficiency, **setState() is generally more efficient for localized state changes within a single widget** or small subtree because it rebuilds only the affected part of the widget tree. 
On the other hand, **notifyListeners() is efficient when managing complex state shared across multiple widgets**, as it allows you to update only the widgets that are directly listening to the specific ChangeNotifier.