# How to correctly setState with notifyListerners() and variable value change?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am trying to design a widget that can show or hide a card (by updating and rebuilding the current state) based on a boolean value. For this I'm using `IndexedStack` widget. This is the Stateful widget state:

```
//imports and other stuff here

class ShowHideCardState extends State<ShowHideCard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //showHideCardController is an instance of a class I created for toggling the visibility of cards
    showHideCardController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: widget.isFirstCardVisible ? 0 : 1,
      children: <Widget>[widget.firstCard, widget.secondCard],
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to detect a change in variable's value by this `ShowHideCardController` class:

```
class ShowHideCardController extends ChangeNotifier {
  static bool isFirstCardVisible = true;

  void toggleCardVisibility() {
    isFirstCardVisible = !isFirstCardVisible;
    //according to my understanding, this should notify that some value has been changed
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

ShowHideCardController showHideCardController = ShowHideCardController();
```

I have the following button onPress:

```
onPressed: () {
  showHideCardController.toggleCardVisibility();
},
```

What I was trying to do so far is to notify flutter of any variable value change, and call setState() to update the state.

In the debug console, I get this following error:

```
The ShowHideCardController sending notification was:
  Instance of 'ShowHideCardController'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose():
ShowHideCardState#11339(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592887/fluttererror-setstate-called-after-dispose-lifecycle-state-defunct-not) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761888/flutter-calling-setstate-from-other-widget), but I didn't either fully understand the error or the answers failed to resolve the error.

Also possibly [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932355/setstate-vs-notifylisteners-which-one-is-more-efficient) could be the solution to my question. But I'm unable to understand (and thus relate it to my question).

Comment: How do you use your `ChangeNotifier`? How do you access it from your `onPressed` method?

Comment: I call `toggleCardVisibility` in `onPressed` using the instance of its containing class, that function calls `notifyListeners()`. `toggleCardVisibility` is under a class that extends `ChangeNotifier` @PeterKoltai

Comment: But do you use `Consumer`, `Provider.of` or `context.watch`?

Comment: No, I'm not using these.

Comment: Okay, then please review the documentation, [for example](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) here on this scheme. You have to somehow to listen to changes coming from the notifier.